# What is the markup attribute for an html code tag?

Tags: html, css

I was inspecting a site's code to see how they styled a section of code in their page.

This is what I saw:

```
<code markup="tt">
```

I combed through the code to see if it was referenced any other time and it was only referenced in these code tags and there is no other reference to it in HTML or CSS.
(here's the link if you're curious: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

I've been searching online, and I can't find this "markup=''" attribute anywhere. Can someone please explain what it is?

Comment: If it’s not [officially defined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/code), then it’s some custom attribute used by some custom JavaScript and/or CSS code.

Answer (score -1):

you may refer to https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_code.asp for more details on code tag , as explained, code tag accepts all the global attributes of HTML like class, id, name, data attributes and accepts event attributes like onclick, onerror etc. Hence markup is no solicit attribute for  tag here, there are many JS frameworks like ReactJS wherein you can construct the customized attributes or rename existing attributes like class, name etc. to newer names like markup using a concept called "props". E.g. you may refer to this link: https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/08/dom-attributes-in-react-16.html for more clarification.

Comment: ooooooooh! I see, Thank you. I completely didn't understand why it wasn't listed on w3schools or any where else. Basically I'm still a 100%noob and didn't know that these other languages have these capabilities. I appreciate your response and resources!

Comment: Thanks for your comment, could you help me by accepting/upvoting the answer if it proved helpful for you. @vzambrano98